# Messagebox won't show when an event is handled in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, event-handling, viewmodel, messagebox

I have been using Messagebox before and haven't encountered any problems until now, when I recently attempt to use it again on my current task. There are 3 different scenarios of the problem.

FYI, the project is written in MVVM. I added a new viewmodel wherein I accessed a method that checks the status of the shared drive, whether its mounted or not. If yes, disconnect it. Upon disconnection, I needed to send a notification box to the user that the connection was denied before proceeding.

Here's what I've done so far:

**First**, I just simply include the command under if condition

```
if (Network.MountedDrive())
{
   Console.WriteLine("Connection denied");
   Messagebox.Show("Connection denied", "Network Error");
}
```

The problem on this implementation, somewhere in my code crashes w/ a NullReferenceException.

**Second**, I tried to fix the first approach with try-catch

Result: App doesn't crash. The problem now is there's no MessageBox shown, though it was successful to print the console log.

**Third**, I tried simplifying my command to:

```
MessageBox.Show("Connected denied", "Netword Error");
```

This cause another issue, `Attempted to read and write protected memory`

I tried using event handler on my first attempts. Trigger my handler when I accessed the Checking method, though the same issues occur.

I am quite unsure how to solve this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: _somewhere in my code crashes w/ a NullReferenceException_ - find which code line throws this exception.

Comment: _I tried to fix the first approach with try-catch_ - this is not a fix, but moving "garbage" under the carpet ;)

Comment: @Fabio the specific code that crashed w/ NullReferenceException was not my implementation. Before it was working fine, not until I added a messagebox on my viewmodel. Is it possible that part was not really a clean implementation?

Comment: @Fabio thanks for also noting about the "garbage" thing :) I'll remember that